# Loading large data From .net server to android application

Tags: android, .net, json, asynchronous

I have a android application, in which we have to download large amount of data from  MS sql server using .net web service , and have to display in the activity, the problem is there will be around 150 records with 12 columns , will be a large amount of data , the time taken will be larger , causes bad user experience , currently we are using Dataset to pass the data from web service and asynchronous task to download the data, is there any better options that this..

Comment: hi...its long time but similar problem might come for someone...
did you follow pagination?
if it is static data then did you followed sqlite db method?

Comment: we didn't use pagination ,yes we fallow sqlitedb method.